# Find between values from table and function

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following table:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE t1
(
   cola int,
   colb int,
   colc varchar(10),
   cold varchar(10)
);

cola   colb   colc   cold
-------------------------
2      4      x      z
6      8      ab     zub
10     12     jc     me
```

I have the funtion which will return table values.

Function return:

```
f_column
----
1
2
5
11
```

Now I want to display `colc,cold` from `t1` where function result `f_column` between `cola` and `colb` of table `t1`.

Expected result:

```
colc   cold
------------
x      z
jc     me
```

Comment: what is the function? and what will it take as input parameter? does it return table? say more about function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that you said that the function returns a dataset, this **assumes** the function is a table-value function.

With a table-value funciton, you can use `FROM` on it, just like aa table (if you want to "`JOIN`" to it, you have to use `APPLY`). Thus this is a very simple query:

```
SELECT t1.colc, t1.cold
FROM dbo.YourFunction (Parameter1, Parameter2) YF
     JOIN dbo.t1 ON YF.f_column BETWEEN t1.cola AND t1.colb;
```

The example above assumes you have 2 parameters for your function. You'll need to change it to make it relevant for yours.

*Edit: As a full working example:*

```
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE TABLE t1
(
   cola int,
   colb int,
   colc varchar(10),
   cold varchar(10)
);

INSERT INTO dbo.t1 (cola,
                    colb,
                    colc,
                    cold)
VALUES (2,4,'x','z'),
       (6,8,'ab','zub'),
       (10,12,'jc','me');

GO
CREATE FUNCTION f1() RETURNS table
AS RETURN 
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES(1),(2),(5),(11)) V(f_column);
GO

SELECT t1.colc, t1.cold
FROM dbo.f1()
     JOIN dbo.t1 ON f1.f_column BETWEEN t1.cola AND t1.colb;

GO
DROP TABLE t1;
DROP FUNCTION f1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Many assumptions here
It's a table value function, perhaps? - no idea as to parameters it takes, if any

You can use a JOIN to the Function or CROSS APPLY

```
CREATE FUNCTION f_column ()
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN
(
    SELECT Ret =  1
    UNION SELECT 2
    UNION SELECT 5
    UNION SELECT 11

)
GO

CREATE TABLE t1
(
   cola int,
   colb int,
   colc varchar(10),
   cold varchar(10)
);

INSERT INTO dbo.t1
(cola,colb,colc,cold)
VALUES
(2, 4, 'x', 'y') , (6, 8, 'ab', 'zub') , (10, 12, 'jc', 'me') 

SELECT 
 T.colc
,T.cold 
FROM dbo.t1 T
CROSS APPLY dbo.f_column() F WHERE F.Ret BETWEEN T.cola AND T.colb
--JOIN dbo.f_column() F ON F.Ret BETWEEN T.cola AND T.colb

DROP TABLE dbo.t1
DROP FUNCTION f_column
```

Comment: Oh, @Larnu has provided the same solution

Comment: Ha, almost identical!

Answer (score -1):

You need to join your function result with the table. It could be something like :

```
SELECT DISTINCT colc, cold FROM t1 INNER JOIN tf_column WHERE f_column
>= cola AND f_column <= colb
```

assuming tf_column is a temporary table with only one column (f_column)

Comment: You can't use `JOIN` against a function. You have to use `APPLY`.

Comment: The OP specifically states it's a function, not a temporary table. If it were a temporary table, the name would begin with a hash (`#`). For example `#tf_table`.